# cv2.imshow() function does not show the image if user input is taken, but works otherwise

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

I'm writing a code to generate user-defined grids on a 500x500 white image.
The program should request the user for input on grid size and draw vertical and horizontal lines accordingly and finally display the image.

The problem I am facing is that the image is not displayed whenever I call the "getGridSize()" function. But the image display works when I manually assign a value to the variable 'num'

I have tried using cv2.waitKey(0) and cv2.destroyAllWindows() too but in vain.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

width = 500 # Dimensions of the blank, white image

def main():
##    getGridSize()
    num = 4

    generateWhiteImg()
    lineImg = whiteImg.copy() # Create a copy of the white image to draw upon

    for i in range(0, num):
        spacing = int(width / (num + 1))    # Specify the width between each line, for uniform placement
        point = (i + 1) * spacing   # Change the coordinate of the lines to be drawn by fixed amounts
        lineImg = cv2.line(lineImg, (0, point), (width, point), (0, 0, 0), 3)   # Draw horizontal lines
        lineImg = cv2.line(lineImg, (point, 0), (point, width), (0, 0, 0), 3)   # Draw vertical lines

    cv2.imshow('LINES', lineImg)

## Function to get grid size from user
def getGridSize():
    global num # Stores the size of grid to be drawn
    num = input("Enter the size of blank grid: ")
    num = int(num) # To convert string to integer

## Function to generate a blank, white image
def generateWhiteImg():
    global whiteImg
    img = np.zeros((width, width, 3), np.uint8) # Generate a zeros list, i.e., a black image
    img[:width] = (255, 255, 255) # Convert black image to white
    cv2.imwrite('whiteImg.png', img) # Save the white image
    whiteImg = cv2.imread('whiteImg.png')   # Load the same from directory

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There are no error messages.
I expected the code to work as it is. I'm thinking the problem is inside the getGridSize() function

UPDATE 1 : I am using python 3.5.4 for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do GUI stuff with OpenCV, you always need to call the [`cv2.waitKey()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) method afterwards. It ensures the window is displayed and [determines how long the window will stay open](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563).

Comment: I did use "cv2.waitKey(1)" and "cv2.waitKey(0)" but neither worked. The image was only visible for a very small amount of time everytime I closed the shell.

Comment: It didnt change anything if I used "cv2.waitKey(20000)" also. Moreover, it should work just fine with "cv2.waitKey(0)" right? The image shows up for only a fraction of time after closing the shell.

Comment: Where did you put it? I added `cv2.waitKey(0)` right below `cv2.imshow('LINES', lineImg)` and everything works fine. Note that when I used `getGridSize()` the resulting window opened in the background. Also, don't use `cv2.waitKey(1)`, It will open the window for 1 millisecond, to short to see.

Comment: My bad. It was opening in the background all this time! Hey, thanks guys.